# Time to change [pop] flavor(s)

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

I see 12 questions using this tag.
25% of the questions are related to pop-ups.
75% are related to the Post Office Protocol.
So (at the time I'm making this question) we really have two separate topics sharing the same tag.  I believe that is not ideal/desired.

Comment: I would've gone with "Time to [tag:pop] this zit"

Comment: @Insane : Somehow, zits don't tend to frequently be at the top of what I tend to think about regularly.  Something tells me you're Insane.

Comment: We would also have accepted "blow this [pop] stand". Or, to keep the theme of using the tag as the verb, I'm sure you could have gone with a reference to "popping the stack".

Comment: Based on Ben N's 9-day old comment, it seems the pop tag is just unnecessary.  I'm not sure about meta protocol; if I should accept the answer (which I agree with), or if the answer shouldn't be "accepted" until a clear resolution is provided (e.g., some moderator agreeing to make changes).

Answer (score 17):

[pop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pop) as referring to the mail protocol isn't a bad tag. It definitely shouldn't mean "Post Office Protocol" and "pop-ups" at the same time, though. There is already a much more widely-used [pop3](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pop3) (>170 questions). I don't imagine there will be many if any questions about earlier versions of POP, so there's nothing wrong with moving [pop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pop)-tagged POP3 questions into [pop3](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pop3). If there are questions about previous versions, they can keep their current tag.

Pop-up questions don't need a special tag in my opinion; the program/browser tag ought to cover it for categorization/discoverability purposes. Nevertheless, we do have [popups](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/popups).

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think to check if POP3 might already exist.  (At the time I wrote this question, I was also rather hurried.)  Thanks for your input; it's exactly what I was hoping for.  I'm currently thinking there's no need for a pop tag at all, then.

Answer (score 5):

Since POP reached version 3 before Internet popularity became mainstream, and then stayed at that version number, nearly all POP users use POP3.

One solution: split into two tags by renaming POP to POP3, and make a "pop-ups" tag.  However, I haven't been very involved in tag maintenance.  Perhaps experienced people would prefer another solution, such as slapping an E-Mail tag onto all POP3-related questions, and not even bother having a POP3 tag for the measly number of just 9 questions over roughly 5 years.